# What does $\overline B(0,1)\subseteq (\mathscr{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C}),d_\infty)$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> What does $\overline B(0,1)\subseteq  (\mathscr{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C}),d_\infty)$ mean?

Could someone explain the meaning of this?

How can a closed ball be a subset of a metric space of continous functions?

Comment: "How can a closed ball be a subset of a metric space of continous functions?" Here, $\overline{B}(0,1)$ is not the unit closed ball of $\mathbb C$, but the unit ball of $\mathscr{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ for the distance $d_\infty$, that is the set of all continuous functions $f$ of $\mathscr{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$ whose distance $d_\infty(f,0)$ to $0$ (the constant function equal to $0$) is at most $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed unit ball in a metric space $M$ is defined as
$$
\{x\in M:\|x\|\leq 1\}
$$That is exactly what happens here, i.e.

$$
C([0,1],\mathbb{C})\supset\overline{B}(0,1)=\{f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{C}), \|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|\leq 1\}
$$